# issues with ASUS S301L ultrabooks

Tags: intel-graphics, brightness, touchscreen

I just like to tell you what still is a Problem in Ubuntu 14.04 and
should be solved for a nice experience of this distribution.

1. Intel open source Graphics issues (proprietary)

   When attaching HDMI-cable the screen switches to the external monitor and it's fine, but there is no switching back unless restart with HDMI detached

   Black screen appears for like 2 seconds as if I would change screen in the settings; frequency increases with intensity of driver use (i.e. videos or video games)
2. Hotkeys (commonly recognised)

   There is no possibility to adjust brightness with the hotkeys (Fn+F5 and Fn+F6)
3. Touchscreen (commonly recognised)

   The touchscreen is behaving like a mouse

   Configuring gestures for the multi touch screen seems to always end in disabling touch pad gestures
4. Panel symbols

   Battery symbol has got a low accuracy while it determines accurately the energy left; only 5 steps of energy are shown by the symbol.

Thank you all for participating in the solution of these problems! I will stay tuned and edit this list if something has been solved.